# Erro Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de instalar o android studio, consigo abrir um novo projeto, mas esta dando esses erros e não consigo fazer nada.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você tem que clicar e instalar as libs que estão sendo exigidas. Logo depois você sincroniza o projeto novamente que vai funfar de boa.

Comment: já tentei fazer isso e continua dando este erro, acabei de desinstalar e estou instalando novamente, existe alguma outra ferramenta ou plugin para baixar??

Comment: Não cara, não tem nada a fazer. Simplesmente instalar as dependências que estão sendo exigidas e pronto. =D

Comment: não esta conseguindo instalar, parece que não esta sincronizando

Comment: Tenta trocar as versões do `com.android.support:design` e `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` para 25.3.0.
Tem a lista das mais recentes aqui: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: tentei trocar mas continua dando a mesma msg